# Xcode/Instruments/Leaks: can it show a red line where apparently there is no leak?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode-instruments

What the program is doing is simply allocating an object and then releasing it.

I'm new to Instruments so I'm not sure I'm interpetingh this right:

[image: Instruments screenshot]

The red line suggests there is a leak at the point where I allocate that object. But on the details you can see it was released and the refcount went back to 0. So why is there a red line in the first place, what is it exactly telling me?

EDIT: this is the "leak" detected. Code from my UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Plant *plant = [[Plant alloc] initWithWeight:3 withSpecies:@"carrot"];

    [plant release];
}
```

Comment: Could you also add the source for the program?

Comment: There. I don't think it's necessary to post the source for Plant since the leak is reported right here.

Comment: Does `initWithWeight:withSpecies:` store `self` anywhere?  Does it create any blocks?  Does it pass `self` as an argument to any functions or messages?

Comment: No, but while looking at the code to make sure, I found the glitch. See answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

The class had a dealloc method that wasn't calling [super dealloc] at the end.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a @property of type Plant.

then this leak could be explained using

```
self.plant = someobject  //some object retained. /(using setter)

plant = someother object // previous value in self.plant leaked

-(void) dealloc
{
[plant release];
[super dealloc];
}
```